# Accessing @attribute from php object

Tags: php

I'm trying to access values from a PHP object returned from an API. I am trying to get the 'total' atribute.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => ok
        )

    [invoices] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [page] => 1
                    [per_page] => 25
                    [pages] => 1
                    [total] => 5
                )
```

My returned object is stored in a variable called $list.

```
$list->invoices->attributes->total
```

I'm trying to echo / print_r that, but getting nothing?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `@` is a part of the property name, you can't just ignore it.

```
echo $list->invoices->{'@attributes'}->total;
```

Comment: You can just define the @attribute to the variable and access using variable name. Example                                                                               `$abc = '@attributes';                                                                                  echo $list->invoices->$abc->total;`

Answer (score 5):

```
$total = $list->invoices->attributes()->total;
```

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, you don't need to even specify @attributes to read this data.  The key trick to get to it is to cast the result as a string.

So, I know it seems strange, but this will work in this case:

```
 echo (string)$list->invoices['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i used:

```
$att_side = $xml->item->attributes()->side;
```